# create custom tabbar using containerview on swipe animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am creating custom scrollable tabbar using container view i used swipe gesture fo scrolling on swipe i want to do animation on swipe i used UIview.Animate but i can't get animation effect let me show you my code

```
 @objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right:
                print("Swiped right")
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.viewG1.isHidden = false
                    self.viewG2.isHidden = false

                    self.viewC1.isHidden = true
                    self.viewC2.isHidden = true

                    self.secondContainView.isHidden = true
                    self.firstContainewView.isHidden = false

                }
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left:
                print("Swiped left")
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.viewG1.isHidden = true
                    self.viewG2.isHidden = true
                    self.viewC1.isHidden = false
                    self.viewC2.isHidden = false
                    self.firstContainewView.isHidden = true
                    self.secondContainView.isHidden = false
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

In `viewDidLoad()` i write this code

```
  let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture(gesture:)))
        swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
```

can any one please tell me how to do swipe animation or where i am done wrong

Comment: You can also use UIPageViewController for smooth transition.

Comment: Yes but for my requirement container view is perfect can you please suggest me answer for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isHidden` property of `UIView` is not animatable. Use `alpha` property to get the fade `in/out` effect.

Comment: Yes Thanks Its Work For Me